# IDE for C++ and support for wxWidgets

Tags: c++, ide, wxwidgets

What good IDE would you recommend for C++ (GNU) programming, with support for the wxWidget library and a GUI builder/designer all in one? Can be either for windows or linux.

Comment: You would probably get better tools if you dropped the "all in one" requirement.

Comment: No, Code::Blocks is an 'all-in-one' and it fits his needs perfectly.

Answer (score 8):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is good.  It integrates and generates [wxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/) code as well!

Comment: Code::Blocks is the best! Take it from someone who has used it (and wxWidgets) for over a year.

Comment: Indeed, Code::Blocks includes wxSmith so you should have no problem using it for complicated GUI applications.

Answer (score 4):

I can recommend [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/cdt/) with [wxFormBuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/). Not really "all in one" because those are two tools, but they work very well.

MS Visual studio is also good alternative to Eclipse if you are using Windows. Eclipse works both on Linux and Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I'm using MS Visual Studio 2008 and wxFormBuilder.  I prefer the debugger in Visual Studio to the GNU or Eclipse debuggers. For long editing sessions, I use XEmacs.

I don't use wxFormBuilder very often, so I don't miss having it integrated with the Visual Studio IDE.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a [wiki listing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B) of IDE's you could try if you haven't found this already.
Also found [this](http://wiki.wxwidgets.org/List_of_Integrated_Development_Environments), IDE's that have been known to work with wxWidgets.

I also recommend Eclipse. I haven't had much experience on it using C++ but its certainly quite exceptional with Java.

Good Luck!

Answer (score 1):

I have always loved [WxDev-C++](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/) 
The most important reason for using it has been the fact that many of the advanced and third part controls are already added in the IDE and it makes it easy to use them.

Answer (score 1):

Try Philasmicos Entwickler Studio, which should meet your requirements.
http://www.philasmicos.com/content/17-freeware

Answer (score 1):

[Code::Blocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) is really good. Seamless integration with **wxSmith** makes this tool excellent choice. Specially for beginners.

[Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) is more serious and sophisticated tool. It hasn't plugin for GUI design, more difficult in integrating with **wxWidgets**. But it's my choice for some reasons: it widely used (as basic IDE in many fields of development), robust text editor, great number of plugins, etc.

Resume:

- **Code::Blocks**: easy, lightweight, seamless, all-in-one
- **Eclipse + wxFormBuilder***: powerful, robust, widespread

Answer (score 1):

Codelite + wxFormBuilder or Netbeans 7.0.1 Cpp tools + wxFormBuilder. They have friently and native interface's, but very slow copilation. As well, Codelite has distributive for beginners Just-Install-And-Develop, which contains IDE+wxWidgets+MinGW.
So, C::B is the best and fastest, of course ))).

Answer (score 0):

The best ide for developing wxwidgets is [codeblocks](http://www.codeblocks.org/) with [wxformbuilder](http://wxformbuilder.org/). wxSmith works but, wxformbuilder offers more options and easy to use than wxsmith...

Answer (score 0):

Its 2015 and there are more Advanced IDEs that one can use for developing wxWidgets.
You can Find the a of these IDEs here : [WxWidgets Tools](https://wiki.wxwidgets.org/Tools)
Here are the free and best IDEs that I have come across and liked :
[CodeBlocks (wxSmith)](http://www.codeblocks.org/)  - [Latest Stable Version 13.12 since 2013](http://sourceforge.net/projects/codeblocks/files/Binaries/13.12/Windows/codeblocks-13.12mingw-setup-TDM-GCC-481.exe)
[CodeBlocks (wxSmith)](http://www.codeblocks.org/)  - [Latest Un Official release as of today 2/21/2015 rev10080](http://forums.codeblocks.org/index.php/topic,13234.0.html)
[WxDevC++](http://wxdsgn.sourceforge.net/)  - [Latest Version 7.4.2-since 2012](http://sourceforge.net/projects/wxdsgn/files/wxDev-C%2B%2B/Version%207/)
[wxCrafter](http://wxcrafter.codelite.org/)  - [Latest Version as of today, 2/21/2015 its 2.0](http://downloads.codelite.org/wxCrafter/)